# Reduce disk space taken on Windows 7 installation (content in windows dir?)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning

My Windows 7 total size is 29.7 GB. And my C drive is 44 GB. So other programs and some files take the rest of the left size. Now I have only 2.2 GB left of free space. But I want to upgrade to Windows 10, but it requires at least 8 GB of free space.

To increase C drive space, I reduced paging file to 400 MB, disabled shadow copy and disabled all restore points. I also tried clean up, which increased size by somewhat ~500 MB max (this is supposed to delete old update components, but it seems there is not much to delete). Also deleted content in Temp folder and SoftwareDistribution.

**Some more notes.** My `winsxs` folder takes 12.6 GB. I also tried Gparted tool to just shrink my Other Drive and increase C drive, but while doing it, something wen't wrong and I got error after which I could not continue so I had to rollback (also some windows so called free trial tools, don't do anything before you buy it. And even if you bought it, it looks like a scam programs).

So does anyone have suggestions how could I reduce size of Windows? I don't want to format everything or wait ~10 hours to resize drives (which could fail, like it did..).

Comment: Reduce size of WHAT Windows ?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like What do you mean of WHAT? Windows 7? You know it has its own folder where it keeps windows stuff? And why downvote? Cmon rly?

Comment: if your drive is NTFS (it probably is), you can compress it. That might give you enough space for the install.

Comment: Easiest is to move the "other files" to another partition.

Comment: To be perfectly honest, you should probably have more space allocated for Windows 7+ than 40GB total if you are going to upgrade, depending on what you use it for. Windows by itself, with no additional applications, requires a minimum of 16GB of hard drive space. If you plan on upgrading to Windos 7 you should have a minimum of 10GB free (8GB seems a tad low, depending on your setup), the update file by itself is just over 3GB plus the temporary space it need to uncompress and install it.

Comment: Customize the install using http://rt-seven-lite.software.informer.com/2.6/

Answer (score 0):

> So does anyone have suggestions how could I reduce size of those damn Windows?

Your winsxs folder is likely that large due to downloaded Windows update files being stored and other disabled components. Reference [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/174705/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-winsxs-folder-on-windows-7-or-8/) to clean up that directory, added useful extracts below in case link breaks later on.

> The WinSXS folder at C:\Windows\WinSXS is massive and continues to grow the longer you have Windows installed. This folder builds up unnecessary files over time, such as old versions of system components.
>
> This folder also contains files for uninstalled, disabled Windows components. Even if you don’t have a Windows component installed, it will be present in your WinSXS folder, taking up space.
>
> To clean up such update files, open the Disk Cleanup wizard (tap the Windows key, type “disk cleanup” into the Start menu, and press Enter). Click the Clean up System Files button, enable the Windows Update Cleanup option and click OK. If you’ve been using your Windows 7 system for a few years, you’ll likely be able to free several gigabytes of space.

Note: [KB2852386](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2852386) must be installed before you can clean up windows update files as suggested in the article.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please include the relevant parts of the article in your answer in case the link breaks.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and guidance. Edited my answer to include the relevant text to clean this one up.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

You say you already deleted content of `C:\Windows\Temp\`.

Also do the same for folder `%appdata%\..\Local\Temp\`  (paste that path into address bar of your Windows Explorer window – e.g. *My Computer* or *My Documents*).

Generally, search for space elsewhere, not in `C:\Windows`. But your machine looks it needs re-partitioning anyway, so you while you say `I don't want to format everything or wait ~10 hours to resize drives` – well, schedule some time to do it. All other actions only postpone this problem for later time, but they won't solve it.

Comment: So what software you would suggest to use for resizing drives? gparted failed. So is there any other good software that does the job for windows?

Comment: @Andrius – I do not recommend anything specific, but you can check [list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_partitioning_software) or you can try searching/asking at [softwarerecs.se]. If you plan to use the device for 3 years, allocate at least 80GB to the partition, because `C:\Windows\` can easily take **50+ GB** after that time. Mine has some 55 GB.